# tkinker screen create screen entry fail

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter to create a GUI.
There are two screen. The screen A has two button, one to launch the program, the other to launch  screen B for config.

The problem here is that if I run the screen B directly like `configform.ConfigForm()` it work pretty fine, however, if I pass the function to button in screen A to launch, the screen B it created will lost control of all entry access, and default value will not show on screen B.

#### screen A

```py
    # Windows meta
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title('screen A')
    window.geometry('500x100')
    window.configure(background='white')

    tk.Button(window, text="Config", command=configform.ConfigForm, width=30, height=5).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    tk.Button(window, text="launch the program", command=function, width=30, height=5).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    window.mainloop()
```

#### screen B (configform.py)

```py
class ConfigForm:
    filename = "config.json"

    def __init__(self):
        # Windows meta
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title('Create Config')
        window.geometry('500x280')
        window.configure(background='white')

        # Default config value
        self.config_dict = {
            "Email": tk.StringVar(value='example@gmail.com'),
            "User Name": tk.StringVar(value='someone'),
            "Password": tk.StringVar(value=''),
            "Counter": tk.StringVar(value='0'),
        }

        # Windows model
        tk.Label(window, text='Create Config file', font=tkfont.Font(size=20)).pack(side=tk.TOP)
        (input_frame := tk.Frame(window)).pack(side=tk.TOP)
        tk.Button(window, text="Save Config", command=self._save_config_).pack(side=tk.TOP)
        (message_label := tk.Label(window, justify=tk.LEFT)).pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.message_label = message_label

        # input_frame
        for idx, (key, val) in enumerate(self.config_dict.items()):
            tk.Label(input_frame, text=key).grid(row=idx, column=0)
            tk.Entry(input_frame, textvariable=val, width=50).grid(row=idx, column=1)
        window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you done anything to try to debug this? Though, since both files are creating an instance of `Tk`, that is no doubt contributing to the problem. You should only ever have a single instance of `Tk`. If you need additional windows, use `Toplevel`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It solved the problem. I learned tkinker 24 hrs ago and didn't know the toplevel, also I would not ask on stackoverflow if I have clue about it.